# Я(,) по-английски говоря(,) учу

Tags: запятые

Нужны ли запятые?

1. – То есть вы учите французскому(,) по-немецки говоря?

– Нет! Я(,) по-английски говоря(,) учу французскому!

Comment: говоря по-немецки, а не по-немецки говоря, и по-английски. Деепричастный оборот.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запятые поставить нужно.

***– То есть вы учите французскому, по-немецки говоря?
– Нет! Я, по-английски говоря, учу французскому!***

Деепричастный оборот нужно обособить, и нет оснований не обособлять его.